# CopyRecursive not working in FAKE script

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have the following target defined in my FAKE build script.  It is being executed.  I have verified this usuing trace statements.  There is a large file structure in the folder at "MyWebApp".  I get no output at the destination folder.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
Target "Push" (fun _ ->
    let dir= FileSystemHelper.currentDirectory
    let src = dir+ @"\deploy\" + version + @"\MyWebApp"
    let dest = @"c:\windows\temp\deploy\" + version
    CopyRecursive src dest |> ignore
()
```

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [definition](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/FileHelper.fs#L417) of `CopyRecursive`

```
let CopyRecursive dir outputDir = copyRecursive (directoryInfo dir) (directoryInfo outputDir)
```

you may notice it represents the partially evaluated (and, by the way, marked at the moment as [obsolete](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/FileHelper.fs#L398)) function `copyRecursive` having signature `bool->string list`.

Your script sends this partially evaluated function value to `ignore` and, apparently, nothing happens as the result.

In order to allow `copyRecursive` to do its work just provide the missing third input argument of type `bool` that defines if the function should override files with the same names in the target directory. Assuming this is the behavior that you want just change the correspondent line in your script by

```
CopyRecursive src dest true |> ignore
```

This will allow `copyRecursive` to perform its side-effect copying magic returning the list of names of copied files, that you may discard with `ignore`.